# Overheating Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, temperature

I am trying to diagnose an overheating Macbook Pro. When starting up some resource-intensive software, it shows spikes in frequency or temperature.

Are the spikes of frequency above the 2.8Ghz of the cpu specs normal?

Is there anything I can do? It's so bad that the machine will actually shut down abruptly.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yes, frequency spikes like that are normal - it is a feature of these CPU. Intel calls this "Turbo Boost", and allows for for example your 2.8 Ghz Core i7 processor to Turbo Boost up to 3.8 Ghz for peak loads. The CPU automatically handles Turbo Boost, and it is only allowed to happen when all necessary conditions are fulfilled - amongst those are that the temperature is not too high, the power consumption is not too high, and not all cores are actively "busy".

Temperature spikes are also perfectly normal. When the CPU is idle, it uses less power - and thus has a lower temperature than when fully utilizes. The maximum temperature you have recorded is 90 degrees - this is perfectly normal and well within the operating temperature range of the CPU.

As for the abrupt shutdowns of the computer - there are multiple possible causes of this - you haven't really demonstrated that overheating has anything to do with your problem, but check your fans and generally that the machine isn't full of dust. Other possible causes could be battery problems, a faulty sensor, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Very useful. The reasons I feel shutdowns are caused by overheating is because they happen always during a peak temperature

Comment: Sounds reasonable - the junction max temperatures of these CPUs are usually 100 degrees Celcius (you haven't specified which CPU you have). Are you reaching such a temperature? - If so, check the cooling solution on your CPU. I.e. are fans operating properly, are vents blocked, is the thermal paste intact, etc.

Comment: It's a 2.8 GHz Intel Core i7. Yeah, I do reach 100 degrees. The fans seem to be working properly, but yeah, I'll try to open it up and blow compressed air to clean it up a bit.

Comment: Good idea - it doesn't sound like a sensor failure - so you do have a cooling issue. Blocked vents, broken fan, dust, bad thermal paste, etc.

Comment: You could disable turbo with [Turbo Boost Switcher](https://www.rugarciap.com/turbo-boost-switcher-for-os-x/)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it - that's symptom treatment. There's obviously a cooling problem that needs to be solved. Disabling Turbo Boost will make the computer run slower in many scenarios, whereby reducing the need for cooling in those situations - but it won't help in other situations, where you still have the risk of the computer abruptly turning itself off.

Comment: @jksoegaard - of course there is a cooling problem.  That is unfortunately an issue with Macbook Pro's and always has been.  I always undervolt and usually disable turbo but there is no getting around the design.  You are right it theoretically may not always reduce heat (as it may take longer to do the same thing) but in my experience disabling turbo often helps as the cooling on MBPs is just so terrible that throttling them before they throttle themselves is a benefit.  But sure blow the dust bunnies out first as you said :)

Comment: That’s not true in my experience - nor is it according to what I have heard from others. MacBook Pros are definitely not supposed to overheat and abruptly turn off - that is a defect within the hardware of that specific laptop. It is not a design problem common to the MBP. Note that throttling is a different matter - common to laptops from all vendors.